# how to delete motion images raspberry pi 3

Tags: motion

I can not access images taken by webcam in raspberry pi 3. The specific software is called motion. When I try to open the image folder and get a message saying ‘Access Denied’.

Comment: Not Pi specific.  The files will be owned by groups motion/adm.  Use sudo to remove the images.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to stack exchange!

Use the `sudo` and `chmod` commands. to give the everyone(the default user) access to the folder, simply change into the directory(folder) the folder is in using the command line(terminal), and type

```
sudo chmod a+rwx foldername
```

replace `foldername` with the image folder. This should work, if it doesn't, let me know!

Comment: I would say it's better to add the user to the right group? `sudo adduser pi motion`. You are only change mode on the folder. What's about the files in the folder?

Comment: Thanks, I will try what you suggested, by the way I am biginer.

Comment: @FarzadBazrafshan , as Ingo say's, there _are_ other ways of changing the permissions, this is just one method that is almost _sure_ to work. You could also access the folder by just using the `sudo` command, but you'd have to do that every time.

Comment: Thanks i have done what you said and works i delete all images, thank you.

Comment: @FarzadBazrafshan , please click the `accepted` button or check-mark next to my answer to accept it if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For deleting you need to change into the folder

```
cd /var/lib/motion
```

Then you can remove all the files like so

```
sudo rm *.avi
```

**Note** change avi extension to whatever files you want removed